# How do I match variables from FreeRADIUS in PostgreSQL with the LIKE operator?

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, freeradius

In a PostgreSQL query, executed by FreeRADIUS, I want to do something similar to (the table names and values are just examples):

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE city LIKE '%blahblah%';
```

but there is a catch: the blahblah value is contained in a FreeRADIUS variable, represented with '%{variable-name}'. It expands to 'blahblah'.

Now my question is: How do I match the %{variable-name} variable to the value stored in the table using the LIKE operator?

I tried using

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE city LIKE '%%{variable-name}%';
```

but it doesn't expand correctly like that and is obviously incorrect.

The final query I want to achieve is

```
...
WHERE city LIKE '%blahblah%';
```

so it matches the longer string containing 'blahblah' stored in the table, but I want the variable to expand dynamically into the correct query. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, where does the value `blahblah` for `%{variable-name}` come from? Please show a complete example, preferably with create table and insert statements for the table(s). Does FreeRADIUS detect these variable strings and substitute them directly into the SQL? Do you expect to do this within PostgreSQL instead?

Comment: Also, "doesn't expand correctly" how? "obviously incorrect" how? What SQL gets executed?

Comment: Well it's a query I've added to the authorize section of freeradius to do a stale-session cleanup. The idea is to remove sessions with NULL acctstoptime if the new auth request is coming from the same MAC address. As my NAS fails to provide the radius server with a 'Calling-Station-Id' (the wifi station's MAC) field in the Accounting-Request packet, freeradius didn't store the wifi station's MAC address in the callingstationid column during the accounting INSERT.

Comment: So, I modified the accounting_start query to insert Acct-Multi-Session-Id in the callingstationid column of the radacct table instead. Acct-Multi-Session-Id contains the station's MAC, but it's a longer string that contains the NAS's MAC in addition. So in my session cleanup query I needed an UPDATE with WHERE and LIKE to match the %{Calling-Station-Id} variable (expanded dynamically by FreeRADIUS before the query is run) to the Acct-Multi-Session-Id value in the modified callingstationid column.

Comment: So I did, following your advice:
    UPDATE radacct set AcctStopTime=('%S'::timestamp - '%{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}'::interval), AcctTerminateCause='Clear-Stale Session' WHERE UserName='%{User-Name}' and CallingStationId like '%' || '%{Calling-Station-Id}' || '%' and AcctStopTime is NULL;

to close the stale session, and it works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess:

Assuming that FreeRADIUS is doing dumb substitution across the entire SQL string, with no attempt to parse literals, etc, before sending the SQL to PostgreSQL then you could use:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE city LIKE '%'||'%{variable-name}'||'%';
```

Edit: To avoid the warnings caused by FreeRADIUS not parsing cleverly enough, hide the `%`s as hex chars:

```
WHERE city LIKE E'\x25%{variable-name}\x25';
```

Note the leading `E` for the string marking it as a string subject to *escape processing*.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
It raised two warnings about unknown '%' variable

WARNING: Unknown variable '%'': See 'doc/variables.txt'
WARNING: Unknown variable '%'': See 'doc/variables.txt'

but it worked!

The query expands correctly
    `UPDATE radacct set AcctStopTime=('2014-07-28 11:38:11'::timestamp - '0'::interval), AcctTerminateCause='Clear-Stale Session' WHERE UserName='cleaver' and CallingStationId like '%' || 'CC-FA-00-C6-4A-A6' || '%' and AcctStopTime is NULL;`

and it does the job, cleaning the stale session.

Comment: @StoychoGanev See edit for how to avoid the warnings.

Comment: Nope, this is the expanded query.
`UPDATE radacct set AcctStopTime=('2014-07-28 12:20:43'::timestamp - '0'::interval), AcctTerminateCause='Clear-Stale Session' WHERE UserName='cleaver' and CallingStationId LIKE E'x25CC-FA-00-C6-4A-A6x25' and AcctStopTime is NULL`

It seems to fail at parsing the backslashes and
`query affected rows = 0`

Comment: Stupid thing must be consuming the backslashes. Double them. Then please report bugs against freeradius re all this. What a horrible mess. It should be using parameterised queries.

Comment: Thank you very much. Doubling the backslashes did the trick.
The query is now producing the expected result, despite the dirty hacks involved.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE city LIKE '%%'||'%{variable-name}'||'%%';
```

Is slightly cleaner. `%%` is FreeRADIUS' escape sequence for percents.